# Load two columns at start in QColumnView

Tags: qt, pyqt

Is there any way to load more than one column at start in QColumnView?

I tried simulating the click on the desired index in the tree view. Though the click event is received it doesn't load the second column. Tried calling the createColumn as well with the index. But both approaches didn't work.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import os

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class MyModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.checkedIndexes = {}
        self.parentChecked=False

    def flags(self,index):
        flags=super().flags(index)|QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable
        return flags

    def checkState(self, index):
        if index in self.checkedIndexes:
            return self.checkedIndexes[index]
        else:
            return QtCore.Qt.Checked

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole:
            if index.column() == 0:
                return self.checkState(index)
        else:
            return super().data(index, role)

    def setData(self, index, value, role):
        if (role == QtCore.Qt.CheckStateRole and index.column() == 0):
            self.checkedIndexes[index] = value
            self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
            return True

        return super().setData(index, value, role)

    def hasChildren(self,index):
        hasChildren=super().hasChildren(index)
        path=super().filePath(index)

        dirIter=QtCore.QDirIterator(path,QtCore.QDir.AllDirs|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot|QtCore.QDir.NoSymLinks)
        if dirIter.hasNext():
            return True
        else:
            return False

        return hasChildren

class columnView(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.model=MyModel()
        self.model.setFilter(QtCore.QDir.AllDirs|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot|QtCore.QDir.NoSymLinks)
        path=os.path.expanduser("~")
        self.model.setRootPath(path)
        self.ui.columnView.setModel(self.model)
        #print("path=",path)
        self.ui.columnView.setRootIndex(self.model.index(path))

        self.ui.columnView.updatePreviewWidget.connect(self.closePreview)

        self.show()
        openIndex=self.model.index(os.path.join(path,"Documents"))
        self.ui.columnView.createColumn(openIndex)
        #QtCore.QMetaObject.invokeMethod(self.ui.columnView, "clicked", QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection, QtCore.Q_ARG(QtCore.QModelIndex, openIndex))
        self.ui.columnView.clicked.connect(self.rowClicked)
        self.ui.closePushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def rowClicked(self,index):
        print("row clicked=",self.model.filePath(index))

    def closePreview(self,index):
        self.ui.columnView.setPreviewWidget(None)

class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(596, 389)
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.columnView = QtGui.QColumnView(Dialog)
        self.columnView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("columnView"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.columnView)
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.closePushButton = QtGui.QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.closePushButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("closePushButton"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.closePushButton)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.closePushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Close", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = columnView()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Though both TreeView and ColumnView is designed to display hierarchical data, I feel that when compared with TreeView, the ColumnView implementation was given less significance and highly frustrating. In TreeView you can do the above easily with QTreeView.expand(index).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do is to select the row with the index using the [selection model](http://ftp.ics.uci.edu/pub/centos0/ics-custom-build/BUILD/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.7.2/doc/html/qitemselectionmodel.html)

```
self.ui.columnView.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(index,QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Current|QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

This will highlight the row and will load the corresponding next column.

Ref: https://forum.qt.io/topic/76588/loading-two-columns-at-start-in-qcolumnview